# How a server handles requests asynchronously

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, server, architecture

I understand this is basic but was not able to connect.

Suppose a django-server(hosted on a linux system with 3gb ram and 1vCPU and nginx) is serving a request (say R1) which takes around 1700ms.

and during this execution at 100ms a request R2 comes in.

Here, the server is already busy handling R1.

So will R2 have to wait for 1700ms - 100ms = 1600ms?

How is this handled?

Is there something like instances(as in aws) which solves this?

Comment: What is a `django-server`? The one you launch with `manage.py runserver`? I mean - this all depends on what the server is. For example `runserver` will process one request at a time

Comment: yeah..sorry for the misdemeanor, suppose it's running on nginx

Comment: You might wanna read this topic on [Nginx performance](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/). But afaik, this has nothing to do with django. Nginx is the one handling the requests. Django is ready to handle simultaneous requests out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, 1700ms is far too long for a request; if your views are taking that long to complete, you have a problem.

Secondly, all methods of deploying Django involve some kind of multiple process handling. Usually this is done with OS processes, although it can also involve threads. Either way, it is handled by your server, eg gunicorn, uWSGI or Apache/mod_wsgi.

Comment: IMO, this is a very basic answer that lacks important details. For a question that asks *how a server handles requests asynchronously* I'd expect a more elaborate answer. ATM, seems more like a comment to me.